# grunt karma | Jasmine.js tasks issue

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

After running grunt karma, getting below error, the only change which I made, was upgrading the node packages.

```
"grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.8.2",
"karma": "~0.12.36",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.12",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.6",
"karma-jasmine": "~0.3.5",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.0",
```

Error which I am getting after running `Grunt Karma`.

```
Loading "jasmine.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Loading "jsdoc-plugin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Loading "notify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Loading "notify_hooks.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hooker' of undefined
Loading "open.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Loading "shell.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Loading "uncss.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Loading "usemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Loading "GruntFile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
Warning: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined Use --force to continue.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:224:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:301:30)
    at Task.runTaskFn (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:251:24)
    at Task.<anonymous> (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:300:12)
    at Task.start (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:309:5)
    at Object.grunt.tasks (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:164:8)
    at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:45:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

Aborted due to warnings.
Fatal error: Cannot read property 'exit' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exit' of undefined
    at Object.fail.warn (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/fail.js:73:15)
    at Object.task.options.error (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:137:12)
    at Task.<anonymous> (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:221:29)
    at Task.runTaskFn (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:257:7)
    at Task.<anonymous> (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:300:12)
    at Task.start (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:309:5)
    at Object.grunt.tasks (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:164:8)
    at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:45:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/fail.js:57
  grunt.util.exit(typeof errcode === 'number' ? errcode : fail.code.FATAL_ERRO
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exit' of undefined
    at Object.fail.fatal (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/fail.js:57:13)
    at process.uncaughtHandler (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:130:10)
    at process.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:236:26)
    at Task.runTaskFn (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:257:7)
    at Task.<anonymous> (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:300:12)
    at Task.start (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:309:5)
    at Object.grunt.tasks (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:164:8)
    at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/Users/marif/Dev/JavaScript/JavaScript-Boilerplate/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:45:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
```

Hope to get some pointers to resolve the same.

**P.S.** It's been running fine if I use karma using 'karma start test/karma.conf.js' from the terminal. But I have been trying to kick off karma through grunt-karma task as well and that's where it's failing.

Comment: please show your grunt-config, you are probably doing something wrong there. edit: have you installed grunt itself? `npm install grunt --save-dev`?

Comment: I have changed the config now, not getting this issue anymore but getting something else.

Grunt config url - https://github.com/mdarif/JavaScript-Boilerplate/blob/1.3/GruntFile.js

Comment: travis-ci is telling you what goes wrong:  Local Npm module "grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul" not found -> `npm install grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul --save-dev`

Comment: That's the new issue actually, I ad to remove rest of the packages which were not used.